# ForEach loop in PowerShell failing after first iteration

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

I have an array, $Conventional, which I need to loop through and click each time so that I can save the PDFs which are made available after the click().

```
$Conventional = @()
$Conventional = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td") | ? {($_.getAttributeNode('class').Value -match 'NodeDocument') -and ($_.innerText -notmatch 'Library Home')}
```

This fills $Conventional with four `td` elements which I need to loop through and click() each time. The following is my ForEach loop which works fine on the first iteration, however it then fails and returns `System.ComObject` each time after that.

```
ForEach ($i in $Conventional){

    $text = $i.innerText    

    $i.click()               
    while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -Seconds 2}

    $PDF = $ie.Document.getElementById("OurLibrary_LibTocUC_LandingPanel_libdocview1_DocViewDocMD1_hlViewDocument")

    $currentURL = $PDF.href
    $fileName = $baseFileName + "_" + $cleanText

    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $currentURL -OutFile $NewPath\$fileName.pdf -WebSession $freedom
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the array I am capturing. In order to retrieve the PDFs, each one needs to be clicked. 
[image: screenshot of $Conventional array]

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks everyone

Comment: `foreach(){}` sometimes have problems with the collections returned by COM applications because they don't properly implement `IEnumerable`. Try with `$Conventional |ForEach-Object { $_.InnerText }` instead

Comment: Thanks for the response, trying this now !

Comment: Hmm, same issue doing it the way you suggested. After the first iteration, the Array is empty and nothing works. When I remove the $_click() it works and prints the innerText but I need it to work with the $_click() also. Grrrr...

Comment: Instead of using `@()` to instantiate a powershell array variable, use a .Net array with `= New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList` then attempt to add to your array. I wouldn't trust powershell to automatically box the output from `$ie..getElementsById()` so I'd work in powershell to make sure your elements are being returned first, then if they are being casted to your array properly second, and *then* work with each element in a foreach loop after confirming the elements are being formatted correctly.

Comment: Good thinking, thanks. I will attempt to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it works fine unless you press click, then maybe the click-event changes the Document enough to break the element-referenses in your `$Conventional`-array. Try this approach:

```
$linksToProcess = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td") |
Where-Object {($_.getAttributeNode('class').Value -match 'NodeDocument') -and ($_.innerText -notmatch 'Library Home')} |
Foreach-Object { $linksToProcess.Add($_.innerText) }

while ($linksToProcess.Count -gt 0){

    $i = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td") | ? {($_.getAttributeNode('class').Value -match 'NodeDocument') -and ($_.innerText -eq $linksToProcess[0])}

    $text = $i.innerText    

    $i.click()               
    while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -Seconds 2}

    $PDF = $ie.Document.getElementById("OurLibrary_LibTocUC_LandingPanel_libdocview1_DocViewDocMD1_hlViewDocument")

    $currentURL = $PDF.href
    $fileName = $baseFileName + "_" + $cleanText

    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $currentURL -OutFile $NewPath\$fileName.pdf -WebSession $freedom

    $linksToProcess.RemoveAt(0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying this now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason you chose to use  a 'while' loop and pop the values off the array, rather than using a For loop with a counter?

Comment: That doesn't matter. I would actually use a foreach-loop since its only a list of strings. The while loop was leftover from a previous idea :-)